# openpyxlでエクセルのセルの取り消し線を判定したい

Tags: python, openpyxl

pythonでプログラムを作成し、エクセルファイルを処理しています。
openpyxlを使用して、読み込んだファイルの特定のセルを集計するのですが、仕様として取り消し線のあるセルは対象外にしないといけません。

セルを丸ごと取り消し線にしてあるものはstrikeで判定できるのですが、文字列の一部であるとstrikeはFalseとなっていて判別できません。
セルに取り消し線が含まれていることを判定するやり方は無いでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一つのセルに複数のスタイルを持つことについては機能提供されていないようです。
また、公式issueで実装予定もないと回答されています。

- 参考リンク

  - [Text formatting lost on save](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1674)

Comment: やはり対応していないのですね。